# Pointer not taking new value

Tags: c, pointers

For the following function:

```
/*this function removes the topmost item in the stack*/
void pop(Stack * S, NODE * returnNode) {
    stackNode * temp;

    if(S->root == NULL) {
        ERROR("Sorry, cannot pop an empty stack!!\n");
    }
    else {
            temp = S->root;
            returnNode = temp->Item;/*x now points to the topmost node*/
            S->root = temp->nextItem;/*stack points to the rest of the list*/
            free(temp);/*returning memory to the system*/
    }
}
```

I am expecting `returnNode` pointer to have the same value as the `temp->Item`, but when I am inspecting the value in `GDB` it doesn't. Am I missing something?

I should add that the `temp` value is being correctly set.

Comment: C is still call-by-value. No exceptions.

Comment: why the hell are people voting down every question they can? stop with your arrogance, just because you know C doesn't mean you have to vote down everyone else's questions, what a useless attitude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way,

in a function you can only modify the variable the pointer is pointing to, not the value, i.e. an address, of the pointer itself. If you want to modify the value of a pointer, you need to pass a pointer that points to it.

for example

if you have:

```
int k = 5, f = 15, *pk = &k, *pf = &f;
```

and you want to switch the values of pk and pf, you would need a function like this:

```
void change (int **m, int **n) {
    int *help = *m;
    *m = *n;
    *n = help;
}

change(&pk, &pf);
printf("pk ist %i, pf ist %i\n", *pk, *pf);
/* pk ist 15, pf ist 5;*/
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update a pointer as a parameter, you need to pass it's address. Otherwise, you are just updating the value on the call stack, which is local in scope.

```
void pop(Stack * S, NODE ** returnNode) {
    stackNode * temp;

    if(S->root == NULL) {
        ERROR("Sorry, cannot pop an empty stack!!\n");
    }
    else {
            temp = S->root;
            *returnNode = temp->Item;/*x now points to the topmost node*/
            S->root = temp->nextItem;/*stack points to the rest of the list*/
            free(temp);/*returning memory to the system*/
    }
}
```

Comment: A better choice is using the return-value,

Answer (score 1):

you should have `*returnNode = temp->Item;` instead of `returnNode = temp->Item;`.